# Why is the video not loading?How should I load and play a video on a chromeless player?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div id="ytplayer_div1">You need Flash player 8 or higher to view this content.</div>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'> </script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 swfobject.embedSWF
 (
    'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1',
    'ytplayer_div1',
'425',
'344',
'8',
null,
null,
{
    allowScriptAccess: 'always',
            allowFullScreen: 'true'
},
{
    id: 'ytplayer_object'
}
);
var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer_div1");
ytplayer.loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo", 5, "large");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WBFa4/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [YouTube Javascript Player API: Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted),

> When the player is ready, the API will call the `onYouTubePlayerReady` callback function.

Wrap

```js
var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer_div1");
ytplayer.loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo", 5, "large");
```

with

```js
onYouTubePlayerReady = function() {
  var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer_object");
  ytplayer.loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo", 5, "large");
}
```

Take note of `document.getElementById("ytplayer_object")`, where the *id* must equal the *id* attribute passed into `swfobject.embedSWF` here:

```js
{
    id: 'ytplayer_object'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the div name and wrapped the lines inside onYouTubePlayerReady, but it still doesn't work.Check it out here:http://jsfiddle.net/WBFa4/11/

Comment: Ah my mistake, id from `document.getElementById("ytplayer_object")` should be the same as `{ id: 'ytplayer_object' }`. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I am just a beginner at developing apps, so I have plenty of doubts regarding API usages, is there way to contact you(mail, fb , or any other way)?

Comment: [I've created a room for discussion on YouTube API.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28988/youtube-api) Although I am unsure how notifications will work, it's worth the try. If it doesn't work well, do continue to ask questions on Stack Overflow so that other users can reference them in the future.